# Prevent repeat login during development with Passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

We are using the Passport with express-session. when I develop features in my local, Server restarts which kills session every time I make changes to the code as I use nodemon. As a result, I have to login repetitively.

**Here is my question:**

Is there any way that I can config Passport to prevent logging in repetitively during development?

**I'm thinking about:**

(1) allow the session to survive during reloadings

(2) allow Passport to use cookie instead of cookie-session

(3) any other possible solutions will be appreciated

Comment: Like Nathan suggested, use a separate storage for express-session which does not get cleared on server restart. I recommend redis through homebrew https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/1b8a321e7c58499ef9f9441b2faa0aa8. If you want the login to persist even when reloading the browser you can implement remember me-functionality http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-remember-me/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just pick your favorite [storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) (you use the default memory storage, don't you?). The easiest way is to store sessions in a database (like [MySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) or any other, maybe [Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis)) and with each restart all sessions will be stored safely in it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code in this question, but I am not going to be a stingy StackOverflow police officer and try to answer this as best as I can. I am expecting that you have sessions set up properly because you are not reporting any problems with data resetting when sending get requests to URL endpoints on your server.

You can actually set session data with the express session. Depending on what URL endpoint you would like to serve the data:

```
app.get('/url-endpoint', (req, res) => {
  req.session.data-attribute = "data";
});
```

You can then serve this data however you like. I hope this answers your question. If this didn't answer your question, I would recommend editing the question and adding some code.